# Updating inside of the RepaintBoundary from outside

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, cross-platform

How can I update the RepaintBoundary from its outside, is it possible?
I am developing some kind of drawing app and if user hits the button I get screenshot of the container, if user hits the delete button painting is clearing but in my case list of points is clearing but container (drawing itself) do not clearing.

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(//physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              RepaintBoundary(
                key: _signKey,
                child: new Container(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                      setState(() {
                        RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
                        Offset _localPosition =
                        object.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
                        points = new List.from(points)
                          ..add(_localPosition);
                      });
                    },
                    onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) => points.add(null),
                    child: new CustomPaint(
                      painter: new DrawPainter(points: points),
                      size: Size.infinite,
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        points.clear();
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('Sil'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

Comment: post the entire child tree of your `RepaintBoundary`

Comment: no need that `RepaintBoundary` and `FlatButton` are posted I need to update the inside of the `Container` by using `FlatButton` they all given. I do not need an exact answer I just need fundamental.

Comment: if you need fundamental then you need any child `RenderBox` to call `markNeedsPaint` method - but different child widgets do that different way

Comment: I repost my code as you wanted.

Comment: ok, check `CustomPainter` constructor - it has `Listenable repaint` and triggers `CustomPaint` to repaint - the docs say: *"The painter will repaint whenever repaint notifies its listeners."*

Comment: Can you answer with an example code block if possible?

Comment: see `WorldMapPainter` here:  https://gist.github.com/pskink/fc8c1bcc0a4fe67f04b05f3bb0c35e37#file-world_map-dart-L16

Comment: btw you dont need `RepaintBoundary` for it to work

Comment: for getting a screenshot?

Comment: yes, if all you want to save is your `CustomPainer`

Comment: That's good news then what can I use to get a screenshot of `Container`